# Azure function: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: python, pip, azure-functions

I have an azure function written in Python for which I have a requirements.txt file. Two of the requirements are pulled in from private Github repositories using the `git+https://github.com/username/reponame.git@version` syntax. When I try to deploy this function to Azure I get an error stating:
`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

Is there a way to authenticate with Git within the function so that these dependencies can be resolved?

I can't find any documentation detailing how this issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

***I have added the below code in my requirements.txt with PAT Token of my github account and the packages from my github repository got imported to my Azure Functions successfully like below:-***

**My requirements.txt file:-**

```
azure-functions
git+https://pattokenwithaccesstorepository@github.com/username/reponame.git@main
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Function got triggered successfully like below:-**

[image]

[image]

***You can generate the github PAT token by following the steps below:-***

Go to your Github account settings > Developer Settings > Generate new token (classic) > Assign the required permission and Create the Token > Use it in this code
`git+https://pattokenwithaccesstorepository@github.com/username/reponame.git@main` with your username and repository name :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Official [github document](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic) to create PAT token